# Button is not Disabling using ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I've a form and i'm unable to disable the submit button if the fields are empty. Below is the code can any one help me to understand what might be problem?

```
<modal title="Add Navigation" visible="showAddModal">
    <form  id="addform" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div ng-classs="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Client Type</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select name="account" class="form-control m-b w-md" ng-model="navData.clientType" ng-required="true">
              <option value="android">Android</option>
              <option value="ios">iOs</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>   
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Client Version</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control w-md" ng-model="navData.clientVersion" placeholder="" required>                        
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Key Word</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control w-md" ng-model="navData.keyWord" placeholder="" required>                        
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Value </label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control w-md" ng-model="navData.value" placeholder="" required>                        
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">                  
          <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="addform.$invalid" ng-click="addNav()">Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </modal>
```

Comment: Possibly `$scope.addform.$invalid` is not modified in the process?

Comment: I think the `addform.$invalid` condition refers to a form with `name="addform"` rather than `id="addform"`

Comment: @ Aaron Yeah you are right thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state:

> A form is an instance of
>   [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController).
>   The form instance can optionally be published into the scope **using the
>   `name` attribute**.

You have to use the `name` attribute to make the form instance available in the `$scope`, but you're using the `id` attribute:

```xml
<form name="addform" class="form-horizontal">
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```